# ng lint and ng test are freezing/hanging in AWS pipeline build step

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, freeze, aws-codepipeline

Recently the build step in our AWS codepipeline started failing with BUILD_TIMEOUT after 1 hour. Upon inspecting the logs, it turns out the last command run was ng lint which reported success but never returned control to bash.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out this is because we use `npm install -g @angular` without pinning the version. This had recently started installing a newer version of Angular - 14.0.0 - which causes the freezing. Perhaps this is a bug in Angular.

We fixed that by pinning the version to the last one which worked for us - `npm install -g @angular/cli@13.3.7`

Comment: Why global install at all? Just use the version installed as a dev dependency, either with npx or adding a script like "lint", then you don't have to remember to change the CLI version in multiple places.